# Converting saved_model.pb to model.tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Tensorflow Version: 2.2.0

OS: Windows 10

I am trying to convert a saved_model.pb to a tflite file.

Here is the code I am running:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Convert
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir='C:\Data\TFOD\models\ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized')
tflite_model = converter.convert()


fo = open("model.tflite", "wb")
fo.write(tflite_model)
fo.close
```

This code gives an error while converting:

```
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 196, in toco_convert_protos
    model_str = wrap_toco.wrapped_toco_convert(model_flags_str,
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\wrap_toco.py", line 32, in wrapped_toco_convert
    return _pywrap_toco_api.TocoConvert(
Exception: <unknown>:0: error: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): requires all operands and results to have compatible element types
<unknown>:0: note: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): see current operation: %1 = "tf.Identity"(%arg0) {device = ""} : (tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>) -> tensor<1x?x?x3xui8>


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Data/TFOD/convert.py", line 13, in <module>
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 1076, in convert
    return super(TFLiteConverterV2, self).convert()
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 899, in convert
    return super(TFLiteFrozenGraphConverterV2,
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 629, in convert
    result = _toco_convert_impl(
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 569, in toco_convert_impl
    data = toco_convert_protos(
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Ace\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 202, in toco_convert_protos
    raise ConverterError(str(e))
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: <unknown>:0: error: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): requires all operands and results to have compatible element types
<unknown>:0: note: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): see current operation: %1 = "tf.Identity"(%arg0) {device = ""} : (tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>) -> tensor<1x?x?x3xui8>
```

Comment: I know there could be a way of using tf-nightly to solve this, but I do not want to use that.

Comment: What was the tf version with which the model was built?

Comment: The TensorFlow version is 2.2.0

Comment: So you are using object detection using models downloaded from TF2 model zoo.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the updated ones from the new model zoo, the folder name is of the old model name, but the model is up to date with tfv2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finally resolved it!

What I did is use tf-nightly and use the following Python Script:

```
import tensorflow as tf

saved_model_dir = "C:/Data/TFOD/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized/tflite"
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(
    saved_model_dir, signature_keys=['serving_default'])
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

fo = open(
    "C:/Data/TFOD/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized/tflite/model.tflite", "wb")
fo.write(tflite_model)
fo.close
```

This fixes the problem and you can convert to .tflite

Comment: needed a slight tweak for this to work for me -->  fo.close()

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow provides a python file called `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py` in the `model/object_detection` folder which can be used for converting your saved model into tflite format.

[This](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py) is the GitHub link to the file. It is downloaded when you download the models directory.

How you can use it:

```
python object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py \
    --pipeline_config_path path/to/ssd_mobilenet.config \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix path/to/model.ckpt \
    --output_directory path/to/exported_model_directory
```

The expected output would be in the directory
path/to/exported_model_directory (which is created if it does not exist)
with contents:

- tflite_graph.pbtxt
- tflite_graph.pb

For complete usage, you can read the comments inside the file.

Comment: Hey Aniket, thanks for the quick answer. I am getting this error: RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution. Do I need to disable eager execution?

Comment: Try disabling it.

Comment: Ok, I disabled it using `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` and now there is another issue: `NameError: name 'graph_matcher' is not defined`. It happens when `tf.app.run(main)` is called.