# Errors in converting Tensorflow Model to Tensorflow Lite Model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolo

I wanted to use yolov4-tiny in the Tensorflow lite framework to count objects that cross a virtual line in a video.

I converted my darknet weights trained from [AlexeyAB's repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) using these commands:

```
python save_model.py --weights yolov4-tiny.weights --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-608-tf --input_size 608 --model yolov4 --tiny --framework tflite

python convert_tflite.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-608-tf --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-608.tflite
```

You can find the convert_tflite.py [here](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite/blob/master/convert_tflite.py)

The first command is successful using numpy==1.19.0. However, the second one shows these errors:

```
loc("batch_normalization/moving_mean"): error: is not immutable, try running tf-saved-model-optimize-global-tensors to prove tensors are immutable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 213, in toco_convert_protos
    enable_mlir_converter)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\wrap_toco.py", line 38, in wrapped_toco_convert
    enable_mlir_converter)
Exception: <unknown>:0: error: loc("batch_normalization/moving_mean"): is not immutable, try running tf-saved-model-optimize-global-tensors to prove tensors are immutable


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_tflite.py", line 76, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "convert_tflite.py", line 71, in main
    save_tflite()
  File "convert_tflite.py", line 45, in save_tflite
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 762, in convert
    result = _convert_saved_model(**converter_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 648, in convert_saved_model
    enable_mlir_converter=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 216, in toco_convert_protos
    raise ConverterError(str(e))
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: <unknown>:0: error: loc("batch_normalization/moving_mean"): is not immutable, try running tf-saved-model-optimize-global-tensors to prove tensors are immutable
```

I have tried other versions of Tensorflow (2.2, 2.3, 2.4) but I had no luck. **What should I do?**

There is a similar issue raised here: [Tensorflow Issue 44790](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44790)

Here are my system details:
Windows 10, x64
GeForce GTX 1060
NVIDIA Driver 460.89
CUDA 11.0.3
CuDNN 8.0.5.39
Python 3.7.2

Comment: I have found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652692/converting-saved-model-pb-to-model-tflite

I will try to use Ubuntu to run the conversion to be able to use tf-nightly.

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer, I'm still running into the error

Comment: I haven't tried this one yet but I found [this one](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite/issues/285#issuecomment-752953137)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pip install tensorflow==2.3.0rc0
```

and restart runtime before starting conversion

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by following a thread on Github issues.

In google colab, I had this issue if I used the default TF version, which was 2.4.0 or above.
Running `!pip install tensorflow==2.3.0` and restarting the runtime, then converting corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me this solved my problem :

```
import tensorflow as tf

if tf.__version__ != '2.3.0-rc0':
  !pip uninstall -y tensorflow
  !pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0rc0
```

And restart runtime, in order to use newly installed versions.